# Initialize Kong API Gateway with Docker

Tags: kong

Is there any way to configure Kong before starting the container?

For example, in the MySQL image you can mount SQL scripts at `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` and they will run the first time to inicialize the database.

In order to initialize Kong, right now I'm launching bash scripts with curl calls immediately after it starts, but it feels very hacky.

Is there anything similar to MySQL procedure to initialize kong?

Comment: Are you trying to initialize an empty db or repopulate a db with data from a previous instance? There are instructions for running a container with migrations (`kong kong migrations up`) at Dockerhub [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/kong/).

Comment: Initialize an empty DB, but what are migrations?

Comment: In this case a 'migration' gets a database ready for use, which is what I think you're trying to do here, yes? (Other kinds of migration are listed [here](https://www.openscg.com/2017/08/what-is-a-database-migration/), but I think you are talking about schema migration, prepping your db for use.)

In which case you should try the instructions above -- they will start Kong and setup PostgreSQL. Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks @esperluette, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: let me know how it worked!